# I have a recipe that calls for 2 chicken broth packets-what does that equal in bouillon granules?

Tags: chicken-stock

I have a recipe that calls for 2 packets of chicken broth. What does that equal in bouillon granules?

Comment: what part of the world? how old is the recipe? Is a brand specified? I'm pretty sure there is no "standard" size of broth packets, so this info is needed in order to determine how large a packet actually is.

Comment: I don't know. I used to be able to buy a box of chicken broth packets. Now, it is no longer on shelves in Oklahoma.

Comment: do you know how much water the box of packets said to use for each packet? Or can you Google "chicken broth packets" and find a link to the ones you remember buying?

Answer (score 4):

The size of the packets, as well as the strength of both the packets and the bouillon granules, can vary by brand, so the best comparison you have is the recommended amount of water to add to each. If the packets you mention are like [these from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X3XR7HR), then the instructions on the box say to reconstitute them with 1 cup of water each. In that case, look at your container of bouillon granules, see how much is recommended for 1 cup of water (mine says 1 tsp, yours might be different) and use that amount for each packet of broth. I also have some bouillon cubes that say to dissolve in 3 cups of water: for those I would use 1/3 of a cube (the amount for 1 cup of water) to substitute for 1 packet of broth.